# Magento Folder structure

Tags: css, magento, themes, directory, frontend

I am new to Magento...and trying to learn my first theme in Magento. This is a very basic question regarding Magento Folder Structure. When I refer many tutorials video as well as text I saw using two ways in creating folders for a new theme

CASE1 : In a video I saw making a theme by creating two folders named app and skin and creating the theme folder directly under frontend folder.

Eg:-skin/frontend/theme-name/default/css/file.css
app/design/frontend/theme-name/default/layout and template

CASE2: In a text based tutorial I saw making a theme by creating following folders.

```
/app/design/frontend/default/new_theme/ - our new theme
/app/design/frontend/default/new_theme/layout
/app/design/frontend/default/new_theme/template
/skin/frontend/default/new_theme/ - our new skins folder
/skin/frontend/default/new_theme/css/
/skin/frontend/default/new_theme/images/
```

In the First case, Theme name comes first and default comes within theme folder
and in second case, theme name comes under default folder. WHICH ONE IS CORRECT?

When I tried the case1 I couldn't get CSS applied to my theme.

Please enlighten me in this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both can do the same.

But case 1 is more like adding a whole new theme/layer, and case 2 is usefull to make variations on youre theme (e.g. different devices) or edits on some themefiles of a theme without messing up the original theme.

Comment: Thanks Gerard....So case 1 is for starting a theme from scratch and Case 2 is for modifying an existing theme coming along with magento or any third-party themes?